# Linq Update Query error in WP8

Tags: c#, sql, linq, windows-phone-8

I have a table in local storage for maintaining Shopping CART Items. It includes below mentioned rows and the DataContext is also here:

```
   [Table]
public class Database
{
     [Column(CanBeNull = false, IsPrimaryKey=true,IsDbGenerated=true)]
      public int ProductUniqueID { get; set; }

     [Column(CanBeNull = false)]
     public int ProductID { get; set; }

    [Column(CanBeNull = false)]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    [Column(CanBeNull = false)]
    public int ProductPrice { get; set; }

    [Column(CanBeNull = false)]
    public int ProductQuantity { get; set; }

    [Column(CanBeNull = false)]
    public int ProductTotalPrice { get; set; }

    [Column(CanBeNull = true)]
    public string ProductImageURL { get; set; }

    [Column(CanBeNull = true)]
    public string ProductCatID { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
public class MFTDataContext : System.Data.Linq.DataContext
{
    public MFTDataContext(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString)
    {
    }
    public System.Data.Linq.Table<Database> MFTCart
    {
        get
        {
            return this.GetTable<Database>();
        }
    }
```

}

---

Now I am running ITEM QUANTITY Update in query to update Item Quantity. But It shows error.

```
        private const string strConnectionString = @"isostore:/MFTDB9.sdf";

 using (MFTDataContext MFTdb = new MFTDataContext(strConnectionString))
            {
                var itemToChange = (from item in MFTdb.MFTCart
                                    where item.ProductID == singletonInstance.CartItemIDs[singletonInstance.ItemToChange]
                                    select item).Single();


                itemToChange.ProductQuantity = singletonInstance.QuantityChanged;
                itemToChange.ProductTotalPrice = singletonInstance.QuantityChanged * itemToChange.ProductPrice;
                MFTdb.SubmitChanges();

                }
```

---

But it is giving me error:
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.Linq.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: I even tried below code , but doesnt work, gives me the same error.

Comment: MFTDataContext db = new MFTDataContext(strConnectionString);

                var courseTable = from cart in db.GetTable<Database>() select cart;
                Database objDatabase = db.MFTCart.Single(cart => cart.ProductQuantity == singletonInstance.CartItemIDs[singletonInstance.ItemToChange]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var itemToChange = from item in MFTdb.MFTCart where item.ProductID == singletonInstance.CartItemIDs[singletonInstance.ItemToChange] select item;
Database record = itemToChange.FirstOrDefault<Database>();
record.ProductQuantity = singletonInstance.QuantityChanged;
record.ProductTotalPrice = singletonInstance.QuantityChanged * record.ProductPrice;
MFTdb.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: First two lines of your code are working fine. Sorry but,                 record.ProductQuantity = singletonInstance.QuantityChanged;
 is giving me error, An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in XMLParsing.DLL but was not handled in user code

Comment: try after giving static input like record.ProductQuantity = 10 to check whether singletonInstance.QuantityChanged is responding with null or not

Comment: I debugged itemToChange, after execution, it is equal to: 
{SELECT [t0].[ProductUniqueID], [t0].[ProductID], [t0].[ProductName], [t0].[ProductPrice], [t0].[ProductQuantity], [t0].[ProductTotalPrice], [t0].[ProductImageURL], [t0].[ProductCatID]
FROM [Database] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[ProductID] = @p0
}

Comment: means record is equal to null, so, record.ProductQuantity is giving me NullReferenceException, means var itemToChange = ..... line is not correct. ssomething is missing or incorrect

Comment: i mean to say try with manual input as record.ProductQuantity = 10 and record.ProductTotalPrice  =100 and check code is working or not.